# Apache server not working on Amazon server EC2

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a remote Amazon server EC2, there i have been running node.js server on port 8080 with port forwarding 80 to 8080. Now i am trying to run apache server also on port 8000 but it's not working.

But when i login to remote server and do lynx "http://localhost" shows me the apache home page. I am unable to check where the problem is, can you guys help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update your Security Groups (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

make sure to accept inbound TCP traffic on port 8000 if apache is listening on this port